# How could it had happened vs How could it have happened

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense, questions

What is the difference between

> How could it had happened

and

> How could it have happened

It would be better if anyone can show its usage in some kind of situation.

Comment: *how could it had happened* makes no sense.

Comment: *how could it had happened* is grammatically incorrect.  To my knowledge, no normal adult native speaker of English would use that sentence, either in normal speech or in writing.

Comment: _Could_ is a modal auxiliary and modal auxiliaries must be followed by an infinitive form of the next verb. _Have_ is the next verb, and the infinitive form of _have_ is _have._ Not _had._ That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Lawler's comment provides a complete answer:

> *Could* is a modal auxiliary and modal auxiliaries must be followed by an infinitive form of the next verb. *Have* is the next verb, and the infinitive form of *have* is *have*. Not *had*. That's all.

“How could it had happened” is therefore not a grammatical utterance.